# how to move 3d object in XNA?

Tags: c#, model, 3d, xna, move

I want to move a 3d car model, when I press the left or right arrow key I change the angle, when I press the up arrow the car drives.

This is the code in the update method:

```
float dirX = (float)Math.Sin(angle);
float dirY = (float)Math.Cos(angle);

if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Up))
        {
            position += new Vector3(-dirX, dirY, 0);

            if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Left))
            {
                angle += 0.015f;
            }

            if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Right))
            {
                angle -= 0.015f;
            }
        }
```

This is the calculating part, but obviously I also need to move the car on the screen. 
I want the car to move forward, not up, so I thought I should rotate it 90 degrees on the X axis, and also I want to rotate the car when I press the left or right keys.

I wrote this code:

```
world = Matrix.CreateTranslation(position) * Matrix.CreateRotationY(angle) * Matrix.CreateFromAxisAngle(Vector3.UnitX, MathHelper.ToRadians(-90));
```

This code isn't working, can anybody tell me how can I move it?

Comment: Can you be more specific than "this code isn't working". What exactly is going wrong?

Comment: Are you actually doing anything to the car's matrix?

Comment: ChrisF : when i press up and left, the car drives forward but it rotate around itself.

ktodisco:the car matrix is world

Comment: this one works: `world = Matrix.CreateTranslation(position) *Matrix.CreateFromAxisAngle(Vector3.UnitX, MathHelper.ToRadians(-90));`
It moves correctly, but i still need to rotate the car

Comment: So let me try to understand this-- when you use the World you posted in your question, your car moves forward and turns, but does not drive in the direction that you turn it? In that case you will have to re-evaluate how you move the car forward. May I suggest replacing "position += new Vector3(-dirX, dirY, 0);" with "position += world.Forward * <movement speed>" ? Also, in the world matrix, I think you need to rotate the car before you translate it or it will rotate around the universal origin.

Comment: Screenshots demonstrating the improper behavior please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be aware that your Y axis is actually "up", not "forward" (by conventions). While this problem has many solutions, quickest way to fix yours is that:

```
float dirX = (float)Math.Sin(angle);
float dirZ = (float)Math.Cos(angle);

position += new Vector3(dirX, 0, dirZ);
```

Then, you should multiply your transformation matrices in the correct order:

```
Scale * Rotation * Translation
```

Which in your case translates to:

```
// this will rotate car around the Y axis, and then translate it to correct location
world = Matrix.CreateRotationY(angle) * Matrix.CreateTranslation(position);
```

One suggestion, do as A-Type suggested, and use direction * speed.