# How to move object in Goblin XNA?

Tags: c#, xna

I have problem with my code to design a tank in Goblin XNA. My problem is to move this tank on ground marker in Augmented Reality. I got code to move an object, but I get an error that I can't solve. I'm trying to use geometrynodes and the code for moving is using objects.

Below is my code. Can someone help me to use geometry nodes with this code?

```
KeyboardState keyboardState = Keyboard.GetState();

if (keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Right))
{
    yourSprite.position.X += 1;
}
if (keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left))
{
    yourSprite.position.X -= 1;
}
if (keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Up))
{
    yourSprite.position.Y -= 1;
}
if (keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Down))
{
    yourSprite.position.Y += 1;
}
```

[A downloadable version of my program](http://www.2shared.com/file/S5XtyuFf/Tutorial16_-_Multiple_Viewport.html).

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: i can't get the declaration as it's geometrynodes error message is (The Name 'yourspirit' doesn't exist in the current context .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In essence, all you need is a class level `Vector2` (position) and the texture being drawn. I'm sure that the class for `yourSprite` contains these. If you can't get it to work then try the following:

1. At the class level, define a `Vector2` called `position` and set it to your initial position (i.e, centre screen)
2. In the Update() method, use the code you posted, but replace

   ```
   yourSprite.position
   ```

   with

   ```
   position
   ```

   This will update the position we want the character to be located.
3. In your `Draw()` method, again replace `yourSprite.position` with `position`.

Comment: It would be best if you could post the code here, or alternatively, provide the link to the example you have based your game on.

Comment: I will send you the code and links of site that i get this code

Comment: [this link](http://www.2shared.com/file/S5XtyuFf/Tutorial16_-_Multiple_Viewport.html) it's my program you can check how to move the tank thanks in advance :)

Comment: It really would be best if you edited your question and posted the relevant code. That way, everyone on this site has immediate access to it and we can all help quicker. I can't download files on the network I'm on just now.

Comment: it will be hard to post my code as it contain from many pages and it will be better if you check the project all from the file

Answer (score 1):

First you want to create object as seem in this code if you create object please post the error message

```
private void CreateObjects()
    {
        bowlingAlley = new Box(Vector3.One);
        Material bowlingAlleyMaterial = new Material();
        bowlingAlleyMaterial.Specular = Color.Brown.ToVector4();
        bowlingAlleyMaterial.Diffuse = Color.BurlyWood.ToVector4();
        bowlingAlleyMaterial.SpecularPower = 45;

        bowlingBall = new Sphere(3f, 50, 50);
        bowlingBallMaterial = new Material();
        bowlingBallMaterial.Specular = Color.Black.ToVector4();
        bowlingBallMaterial.Diffuse = Color.BlanchedAlmond.ToVector4();

        alleyGroundMarker = new MarkerNode(scene.MarkerTracker, "AlvarGroundArray.xml");

        groundNode = new GeometryNode("Ground");
        groundNode.Model = bowlingAlley;
        groundNode.Material = bowlingAlleyMaterial;

        groundNode.Physics.MaterialName = "Ground";
        groundNode.Physics.Interactable = true;
        groundNode.Physics.Collidable = true;
        groundNode.Physics.Shape = GoblinXNA.Physics.ShapeType.Box;            
        groundNode.AddToPhysicsEngine = true;


        // Create a parent transformation for both the ground and the sphere models
        TransformNode transformBowlingAlley = new TransformNode();
        transformBowlingAlley.Translation = new Vector3(0,-10,-20);

        // Create a scale transformation for the ground to make it bigger
        TransformNode groundScaleNode = new TransformNode();
        groundScaleNode.Scale = new Vector3(400, 400, 10);

        // Add this ground model to the scene
        scene.RootNode.AddChild(alleyGroundMarker);
        scene.RootNode.AddChild(transformBowlingAlley); 
        alleyGroundMarker.AddChild(groundScaleNode);
        groundScaleNode.AddChild(groundNode);

    }
```

Comment: What is the declaration of groundNode , bowlingAlley , bowlingBallMaterial , bowlingBall and alleyGroundMarker.

Comment: You can replace this by your objects , any way look this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9240680/how-to-move-3d-object-in-xna?rq=1)